# Conditional probability exercise does not match my intuition

Tags: probability

I have been given the following exercise:

> Consider the experiment of tossing a fair coin 7 times. Find the
>   probability of getting a prime number of heads given that heads occurs
>   on at least 6 of the tosses.

Intuitively, I would say that the only prime number possible, given that 6 heads occur is 7, hence the experiment returned heads either 6 or 7 times, thus the probability should be 1/2.

However, introducing the events:
$$
A := \text {the experiment returned a prime number of heads} \\
B:= \text {the experiment returned at least 6 heads}
$$
then we are clearly asked for the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(A|B)$.

Let me compute:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{1}{2^7}.
$$
For $\mathbb{P}(B)$, I would do:
$$
\mathbb{P}(B) = \frac{1}{2^7} + 7 \frac{1}{2^7},
$$
where the first term in the sum considers the case that exactly 7 heads appear, while the second term considers the case with exactly 6 heads and exactly one tail (the tail can appear on any of the 7 tosses).

The result would give:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}=\frac{1}{8},
$$
which however is in contrast with my first intuition. Is my computation correct?

Comment: This reminds me a bit of the argument that tomorrow the sun will either rise or not rise; therefore the probability that the sun will rise tomorrow is $1/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct this far:

> Intuitively, I would say that the only prime number possible, given that 6 heads occur is 7, hence the experiment returned heads either 6 or 7 times,

Where you go wrong is in the part that comes after.
You assume since there are two possible outcomes,
they must be equally likely.
But you actually are much more likely to toss $6$ heads on $7$ coins than to toss all heads.

In fact, $6$ heads is exactly $7$ times as likely as all heads,
because only one sequence of tosses is all heads whereas there are $7$ different sequences that have exactly $6$ heads, and the sequences *are* equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is wrong.  I'm not sure how you are getting $1/2.$  You may be thinking that once we have $6$ heads, the probability is $1/2$ that the next toss will also be heads, but this is valid only if we are told that the first $6$ tosses (or some other specified $6$ tosses) are heads.

Otherwise, you may be thinking that since there are only two possibilities, ($6$ heads or $7$ heads) they are equally likely, but we are actually $7$ times as likely to get exactly $6$ heads as $7$ heads.